# How to animate a cape with cloth?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am just a beginner at blender and can't really understand what is wrong with my project. This is my first blender project that doesn't have an exact tutorial on YouTube.

I want to wear the scout regiment jacket from Attack On Titan anime.

[image: scout regiment jacket]

I first shot footage of myself and then 3D tracked using an online AI and then tried to have that jacket simulation. I didn't want it to be perfect, but somewhat close.

[image: starting mesh]
[image: start of the sim]

But once the area of the jacket around the hoodie touches the back of the model's neck, the whole cloth starts to get sucked into the model and it's total chaos.

[image: starts to touch the back of the neck]
[image: starts to get sucked in]
[image: total chaos]

I've Searched on google, and watched YouTube tutorials on cloth simulation but this problem just wouldn't go.

I even tried adding some friction to prevent it to touch the neck, but it still does it eventually later in the animation.

I also tried increasing weight but it didn't work.

Someone told that cloth sim should be baked at 5 times size, but the problem still remained the same.

I need help to continue

Project file link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13_kb7axyjB9tXsFs_0As7wuU-YnnNuZa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file?

Comment: cloth simulations can be very complicated and frustrating if you don't know what "screws" you have to turn that it works. So maybe you should start watching some beginner cloth tutorials....of course you can increase the quality steps (which normally help a lot) and without seeing your settings/blend file we can't really help you. Another problem might be non applied scale/rotation.

Comment: I agree with Chris, so take my comment with the grain of salt it's worth and may not help at all... but... In the collisions section, try to add a very slight amount of *Impulse Clamping* that sometimes helps around complex meshes like a character mesh.  Additionally, I have sometimes had to make a (hidden) low-poly version of my character mesh that is the Collision object and that has also helped.